how to load page into a div when click on a link without reload the window?
i have this html+php code :
<div class="categories_menu">               
<?php foreach($pt->categories as $key => $category) {
if (1) { ?>
<div class="items">
<a class="item_link" href="{{LINK videos/category/<?php echo $key?>}}" ><?php echo $category?></a>
</div>
<?php } }?>
</div>

<div id="load_cats" class="load_cats">  
 <!--load categories contents in this div -->         
</div>

the first code create a menu for categories by the php foreach methode.
this code :
<a class="item_link" href="{{LINK videos/category/<?php echo $key?>}}" ><?php echo $category?></a>
when click on it will open category page as a new page outside the current page.
i want to open category page inside the div id="load_cats" without reload/refresh the current page .
the matter is open category inside the div instead of open the url in a full new window in browser.
this code can help but what is the code to load categories pages !!
$(".item_link").click(function() {
    $("load_cats").load("???");
});

i see on this site many topics speak about this , but because my code based on php foreach i cant use them .

"but because my code based on php foreach i cant use them" - why would that be?

You need this
$(() => {
  $('.categories_menu').on('click','.item_link',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link
    $('#load_cats').load(this.href);
  });
});

Assuming this generated html, and that /videos/category/key1 will load an HTML partial
<div class="categories_menu">               
  <div class="items">
    <a class="item_link" href="/videos/category/key1" >key1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <a class="item_link" href="/videos/category/key1" >key1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <a class="item_link" href="/videos/category/key1" >key1</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="load_cats" class="load_cats">  
 <!--load categories contents in this div -->         
</div>


works 100% . perfect work . thanks
